# question about qsort implementation

Tags: c++

i have implement this code from programming pearls and i think it should be correct but it gives me this mistake
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
using std::qsort;
int charcmp(char*x,char *y){   return *x-*y;}
#define wordmax 100
int main(void){
    char word[wordmax];
    char sig[wordmax];
    while(scanf("%s",word)!=EOF){
        strcpy(sig,word);
        qsort(sig,strlen(sig),sizeof(char),charcmp);
        printf("%s %s\n",sig,word);
    }


     return 0;
}
```

mistake:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: anagrams, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  anagrams.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\anagrams\anagrams.cpp(11): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(304) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\anagrams\anagrams.cpp(13): error C2664: 'qsort' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'int (__cdecl *)(char *,char *)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(const void *,const void *)'
1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

i think jon bentley  should know such kind of topic yes why is such kind of mistake?

Comment: The error message is fairly clear: "cannot convert parameter 4 from 'int (__cdecl *)(char *,char *)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(const void *,const void *)'".  Have you looked at the types of the value it is expecting for that argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `charcmp` function needs to take `const void*` parameters:

```
int charcmp(const void* x, const void* y)
{   
    return *(const char*)x - *(const char*)y;
}
```

The error message:

> cannot convert parameter 4 from `'int (__cdecl *)(char *,char *)'` to `'int (__cdecl *)(const void *,const void *)'`

is telling you that the argument you are passing (a pointer to the function `charcmp`) does not have the correct type to be passed into `qsort`.

Since this question is tagged as C++, you might consider using `std::sort` instead; it is type safe and much easier to use:

```
std::sort(sig, sig + strlen(sig));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error to lookout is

```
int (__cdecl *)(char *,char *)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(const void *,const void *)'
```

The function expects arguments of type **const void***.